# TimeSpan format reading from SQLite to datGridView

Tags: c#, sqlite

After a lot of googling and trying, I am still not able to do this:

Put the C# TimeSpan value greater than 24 hours into a numeric SQLite table column and get it back in .NET DataGridView in the right format for these larger time span values.

If I do something like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into test (s) values (@s)";
cmd.CreateParameter<TimeSpan>("s", new TimeSpan(23,59,59));
```

then

```
cmd.CommandText = "select time(s) as s from test";
```

and link the result with the DataGridView

I can see right formated value 23:59:59 in the column s.

After I put in any larger TimeSpan, the column stays empty (with no error message) and no other formating function helped I had been trying.

However, both SQLiteAdministrator and SQLite Datbase Browses show e.g. 1.00:59:59 with TimeSpan(24,59,59) into insert command so the value in the table is obviously OK.

Please could somebody tell me, how to achieve the 1.00:59:59 format reading?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This link may be of some help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx

```
duration.ToString("dd\.hh\:mm\:ss")
```

You should also not need the 'time(s) as s' in your select statement, instead just write:

```
select s from test
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the format I need but there is still the problem - where or which way to use it? Doing something like this:    
`dataGridView1.Columns["s"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = @"dd\.hh\:mm\:ss";`    
makes nothing...